# Formtoemailer.php fails to initiate Autoreply

Tags: php, email

I have a Dreamweaver form which collects the relevant data and a PHP script 
(Supplied originally by dreamweaverspot.com who no longer exists) which  collects data and emails it to a registration mailbox. On receipt the registration mailbox has been sending an autoreply back to the person who completed the form and forwards a copy to whoever is backing up registration (this still works). The auto reply to the sender has stopped working.

I have spoken to my hosting support who have concluded the PHP script is not using SMTP and therefore is not being serviced by the autoreply facility. This is based on any email sent directly to the registration mailbox is responded to properly and only the email generated by the script is failing.

To date I have tried:

```
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "smtpout.europe.secureserver.net"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;  // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)

mail($my_email,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

which gives me a "Server not Found" error.

Comment: Not sure if this will do it but try adding `$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;`

Comment: Also `$mail->AddAddress('chris.cox@yourcompany.com');`

Comment: `$mail->Subject = 'Some subject';`

Comment: `$mail->Body= 'Some body';`

Comment: Finally, `$mail_result = $mail->send();`

Comment: Check for errors `echo $mail_result;`. You do not need to use the `mail();` call like you show in your example